# Wait for line to be added to a file MATLAB

Tags: matlab, select

I have a log file into which another process is dumping data.  I would like to plot the last (most recent) line of the file in MATLAB immediately after it is written, each time it is written.

I there a MATLAB (or octave) equivalent for the "select" posix syscall?

Answer (score 0):

I found one way, but it's not portable, and you can't dump out of it with Ctrl-C if you need to:

```
system('inotifywait -qq -t 1 -e modify foo.dat');
```

You need to be running linux with the "inotify-tools" package installed.